# String is empty when I try bind in from a component to a html file

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript

Im currently trying to create a mean stack app and I've followed a tutorial up tot this point but where I have {{ message }} its should be filled with the exported variable message from the component, but it just stays blank. I've tried debugging it in the browser and different text editors but nothing shows up and feel like its just boiling down to a something small Im missing, Im still new to angular 2.0.

My Angular Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'Employees',
  templateUrl: 'employees.component.html'
})

export class EmployeesComponent {
     message = 'A message';
}
```

The HTML that the message should appear in:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">


</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron" id="juminfo" >
        <h1 id="yesthead" class="display-3" class="text-center col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">Company Employees</h1>
        <p id="info" class="lead" class="text-center col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">This section is used to review the staff of the company who are currently employed, use the search bar to look for someone.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bs-example">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">1. What is HTML?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    {{ message }} 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try `templateUrl: './employees.component.html'` path should be relative

Answer (score 0):

I guess the app is not bootstrapped correctly. I've created a plnkr example of your code to make it easy to understand. Please check the `[http://plnkr.co/edit/RCawJp7Zzx2vzeKOjZtx][1]`

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have the bootstrap set up in the index file and ive tried to implement your design a few different ways but I've been getting Unhandled Promise rejection where Employees should be

Comment: Did you add your Employees Component to the App module declaration like below.

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, EmployeesComponent],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})

Comment: Yes I fixed it in the end it turned out it was a problem with compiling the Typescript, thanks for the help.